# Python 3 keeps printing none

Tags: python

I know that a function returns None as default, but my problem seem to be coming from int/input/print ???

```
n1 = int(input(print('First number : ')))
n2 = int(input(print('Second number : ')))
```

And here's the result

```
First number :
None12       <~~~typed in 12 then Enter
Second number :
None
```

Comment: Your code please.

Comment: Add it to the question!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the print() call. The input() function only takes a string as a parameter, and print doesn't actually return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call `print` function here:

```
n1 = int(input("First number: "))
n2 = int(input("Second number: "))
```

Answer (score -1):

As they told you before input only takes strings while print is a function this is how you should write it if you want to use print :

```
n1 = int(input('First number : '))

n2 = int(input('Second number : '))

print(n1)

print(n2)
```